# MS Excel: How do I make cell references variable?

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I probably didn't word that title correctly, so let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I need to find cycles in a series of data.  So let’s say I have all of my data in column A of an Excel spreadsheet.  If a condition that I’m looking for is true in, say, cell A7, I want to check to check if it’s true in every second cell (A9, A11, A13 and so forth).  If it’s not true in every second cell, I want to adjust the model to check every third cell starting with that A7 cell (A10, A13, A16, and so on).  If the condition is not true in every third cell, then I want to check every fourth cell (A11, A15, A19, etc.).

Programming the formula to check if the condition is true should be somewhat easy using either IF or AND formulas.  My problem is how do I change the model to switch from every second cell to every third cell, and then run it to check every fourth cell, and so on.  I’d like to, say, set up the formulas in column B and have cell C1 be a user input that determines which cells are used in the formulas in column B.  Is there a way to do this?

Example: if cell C1 says “2”, then the formulas in column B check every other cell in column A, and if I change the value in cell C1 from “2” to “3”, then the formulas in column B switch from checking every second cell to checking every third cell and report back to me.

I could just manually change the cell references in the formulas in column B, but that could take bloody ages and I figure there’s got to be a better way.

So I’m looking to make the cell references ‘variable’ in a sense.  Instead of hardcoding the cell references and saying “look at cell A7, then look at cell A9, then look at cell A11…” I want to tell Excel “look at A7, then the next cell you look at is dependent upon what I say in cell C1.”

Comment: You can use Indirect() to reference cells. e.g. =INDIRECT("A"&C1 * ROW(B2))

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows my setup:

[image]

I have simple data in column A. Column B determines whether the formula in C should be evaluated. For example, B2 contains the following formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A2),$D$2)=0,1,0)
```

Column C would contain the logic you want to apply. In this case, I return the data in A if B is 1; otherwise, I return "":

```
=IF(B2=1,A2,"")
```

Column D determines the number of rows to skip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one column, this formula would go in B1 and you can drag it down. Update the $A$1:$A$20 range to include your entire range. This formula will check whether the previous cell in your cycle (every 2,3,4,etc) matches.

```
=IF(AND(ROW()>$C$1,MOD(ROW(),$C$1)=0),INDEX($A$1:$A$20,ROW()-$C$1)=$A1,"")
```

Do not use INDIRECT...ever.

Comment: How about when the sheet name is variable based on the value in another cell, can I use it then?  Because I do not think you can use INDEX for that.

Comment: Sheet names should never be variable. All raw data should be structured in a single table in a single tab. Whatever criteria is used to differentiate between tabs should just be an additional field on the table.

Comment: Of course this is in a perfect world and we all come across spreadsheets that we just have to make work without rebuilding the entire thing. If forced to look at multiple tabs, I would use CHOOSE instead. If you have like 100 tabs and the names are changing, just give up and throw away that spreadsheet!

Comment: I will disagree.  I have a workbook that does thousands of calculation based on tables imported from a PDF.  Because of un savvy users and the format of the PDF I had to have one tab per page.  Then there are other tabs with the same setup that are interpolated.  This is again for the un savvy to check.  Then I do calculation behind the scenes to do what you said.  But to get there I had to use INDIRECT to make it easier to create the interpolated sheet, since there are hundreds of formula it was better to use cells with the sheet names.  There are always exceptions.

Comment: I do agree it should be avoided like the plague, but to state `Do not use INDIRECT...ever.` is not possible.  Another is when using it in an array formula to iterate through an unknown value `ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & B1))` which when used in conjunction with LARGE() will return the top n where n = the value in B1.

Comment: It is possible. Maybe it requires some VBA or re-designing some processes, but it IS possible. Anything imported from a PDF could easily be dumped into a single table. I'm not saying INDIRECT is so bad it's worth redesigning all our existing spreadsheets to get rid of it. That's a personal judgement call. However, I will say it is NEVER the best solution and should never be suggested as such.